# Issue in getting wrong latitude - longitude in php codeigniter using google map library

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, marker

Hello friends i wan to drop multiple pin in google map php  codeigniter so below is my code , i used google map library for that.

**CODE**

```
$this->load->library('googlemaps');
$config['cluster'] = TRUE; 
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config); //$address[ ]=$add; //store your multiple address in array
// _debug($address);
foreach($data['detail'] as $add)
{
$p_address = $add['p_address'];
$p_city = $add['p_city'];
$p_state = $add['state_name'];
$p_zipcode = $add['p_zipcode'];
$finaladd = $p_address.', '.$p_city.', '.$p_state.', '.$p_zipcode;
//_Debug($finaladd);

    $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$finaladd);
     $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
    $output= json_decode($geocode);
    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = $lat.','.$long;
    $marker['infowindow_content'] = $finaladd;
    $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart? chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|e02222|000000';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

}

$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

when i run above code at that time i m getting wrong latitude and longitude value so for that my pin drop in wrong  place  so any idea how can i solve this problem ? your all suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: If you manually enter the API URL, does it show the right values?

Comment: What is the output of  `$prepAddr` variable??

Comment: Ofir Baruch : no it shows wrong value of latitude and longitude

Comment: saty  : in `$prepAddr` i get my address value which i pass

Comment: since you have checked it manually and are getting same result, so code should be working fine, i would suggest that try to add some additional detail in address, because there might be many similar places for the search query you are trying, in detail data would fetch most appropriate data.